# PyQt4 - Hyphenation in Label

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, hyphenation

I have many strings like:

```
"Hy~~phen~~a~~tion by Com~~put~~er"
```

and want to display them in a Label. The "~~" marks a point for hyphenation and thus should not be displayed BUT used for hyphenation.

Is there any way to enable hyphenation for a QT4 Label and if so how do I have to mark the point where hyphenation should be allowed?

The goal is basically to have the same behavior as if I would exchange the ~~ with "-" but that the "-" is only displayed if an actual wrap happened.

e.g.:

```
Hyphena-
tion by
Compu-
ter
```

Is this possible with Qt4?

Comment: Although it's not necessarily a good solution, might you be able to modify the string based on the character length of the text box - essentially perform the wrapping yourself. You could probably inherit from the textbox to do this.

Comment: Well, the problem is, I have to be able to change the font later on. And doing the wrapping manually while respecting the current font could easily get more complex than the program itself.

Comment: you can inspect `lineWrapColumnOrWidth()` to see where the line wrap _would_ occur if it was left to its own devices. I did something similar with QML and hacked it using a dummy text box that just gave me the sizes.